# Trying to display the current time in both standard and military format

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

print("The current standard time is: " + now.str)
```

I'm relatively new to python coding so I'm having trouble on some basic stuff, but I can't figure out how to code this correctly, nor do I have even the slightest idea as to how to have military time print out. [The prompt in question][1]

[Edit]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPyZF.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKCsM.png

Answer (score 0):

`str(now)` is military time... `now.strftime(FORMAT_STRING)` will allow you to use whatever format you would like to use (ie not sure what "standard" format means) you should read the docs https://strftime.org/

for example

```
>>> now.strftime("%B")
'September'
```

Comment: Appreciate the assistance. To clarify, standard time is the 12-hour clock :)

Comment: im not going to give you the exact format ... but with the link i provided you should be able to manage no problem :)

Comment: The standard time is displaying correctly, however when using str(now) it displays the exact same time as the 12-hour clock, is there a way I can send the image of the problem in a comment?

Comment: you could edit the original question :)  time less than 12:00 (noon) will be the same in millitary time or in standard time ... presumably you are seeing a timestamp for the morning of sept. 30

Comment: It's around 30 past midnight where I'm at haha, I wish I had that luxury at the moment. But yes I am. The image is updated in the OP ^^

Comment: you could try using format `"%x %X"` which should format the date the same way it is formatted on your computer when you look in the bottom right corner